# Semver comparison using JQ

Tags: json, comparison, jq, semantic-versioning

I have a array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "version": "2.3.4"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "version": "1.4.4"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "version": "0.0.4"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "version": "1.3.4"
  },
]
```

And I need to get all the objects where the version is "1.2.0".
I am interested in a built in way using JQ but I cannot find anything related. Maybe it does not exist?

I know I could do some ugly regex hack here, but what would be the right way to solve this so I can easily swap my condition so if instead of 1.2.0 maybe in a short time in the future lets say I want the objects with version greater than 1.2.7 for instance?

Comment: There is NO semver comparison library/module in jq. It could be added in the future releases but not as of jq-1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have the option of parsing and implementing the comparisons.

```
def _parse_semver($with_op):
    if type == "string" then
        capture(if $with_op then "(?<op>[~])?" else "" end
        + "(?<major>\\d+)\\.(?<minor>\\d+)(?:\\.(?<patch>\\d+))?"
        + "(?:-(?<prerelease>[A-Z0-9]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9]+)*))?"
        + "(?:\\+(?<build>[A-Z0-9]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9]+)*))?"; "i")
        | (.major, .minor, .patch) |= (tonumber? // 0)
    elif type == "object" and ([has(("major,minor,patch,prerelease,build"/",")[])]|all) then .
    else empty end;
def parse_semver: _parse_semver(false);
def cmp_semver($other): parse_semver as $a | ($other|_parse_semver(true)) as $b |
    def _cmp($other): if . == $other then 0 elif . > $other then 1 else -1 end;
    def _cmp_dotted($other):
        if . == null then 1
        elif $other == null then -1
        else
            reduce ([split("."), ($other|split("."))] | transpose[]) as [$a, $b] (0;
                if . != 0 then .
                elif $a == null then -1
                elif $b == null then 1
                else
                    ($a|test("^\\d+$")) as $anum | ($b|test("^\\d+$")) as $bnum |
                    if [$anum,$bnum] == [true,true] then $a | tonumber | _cmp($b | tonumber)
                    elif $anum then -1
                    elif $bnum then 1
                    else $a | _cmp($b) end
                end
            )
        end;
    # slightly modified version of https://semver.org/#spec-item-11
    if $a.major != $b.major then
        if $a.major > $b.major then 1 else -1 end
    elif $a.minor != $b.minor then
        if $a.minor > $b.minor then 1 else -1 end
    elif $a.patch != $b.patch then
        if $a.patch > $b.patch then 1 else -1 end
    elif $b.op == "~" then
        0
    elif $a.prerelease != $b.prerelease then
        ($a.prerelease | _cmp_dotted($b.prerelease))
    elif $a.build != $b.build then
        ($a.build | _cmp_dotted($b.build))
    else
        0
    end;
def cmp_semver($first; $second): $first | cmp_semver($second);
```

Then utilize the new comparison functions:

```
$ jq 'map(select(.version | cmp_semver("1.2.0") > 0))' input.json
[                                                                                                                                     
  {                                                                                                                                   
    "id": 1,                                                                                                                          
    "version": "2.3.4"                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                  
  {                                                                                                                                   
    "id": 2,                                                                                                                          
    "version": "1.4.4"                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                  
  {                                                                                                                                   
    "id": 4,                                                                                                                          
    "version": "1.3.4"                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                   
]

$ jq -rn '("1.0.0-alpha<1.0.0-alpha.1<1.0.0-alpha.beta<1.0.0-beta<1.0.0-beta.2<1.0.0-beta.11<1.0.0-rc.1<1.0.0"/"<") as $input |
    range($input | length-1) |
    "cmp_semver(\($input[.]|tojson);\t\($input[.+1]|tojson))\t-> "
    + "\(cmp_semver($input[.]; $input[.+1]))"'
cmp_semver("1.0.0-alpha";       "1.0.0-alpha.1")        -> -1                                                                         
cmp_semver("1.0.0-alpha.1";     "1.0.0-alpha.beta")     -> -1                                                                         
cmp_semver("1.0.0-alpha.beta";  "1.0.0-beta")   -> -1                                                                                 
cmp_semver("1.0.0-beta";        "1.0.0-beta.2") -> -1                                                                                 
cmp_semver("1.0.0-beta.2";      "1.0.0-beta.11")        -> -1                                                                         
cmp_semver("1.0.0-beta.11";     "1.0.0-rc.1")   -> -1                                                                                 
cmp_semver("1.0.0-rc.1";        "1.0.0")        -> -1
```

---

At first I wasn't sure if it was possible to use arrays as the semver key, but it appears it is possible, but requires some additional data points to sort on.

```
def semver_key: parse_semver | [
    .major, .minor, .patch,
    .prerelease==null, ((.prerelease//"")/"."|map(tonumber? //.)),
    .build==null, ((.build//"")/"."|map(tonumber? //.))
];
```

This allows you to sort by the versions.

```
$ jq -rn '
("1.0.0-alpha<1.0.0-alpha.1<1.0.0-alpha.beta<1.0.0-beta<1.0.0-beta.2<1.0.0-beta.11<1.0.0-rc.1<1.0.0"/"<") as $input |
[$input, ($input | sort_by(semver_key))] | transpose[] | "\(.[0])\t\(.[1])"
'
1.0.0-alpha     1.0.0-alpha                                                                                                           
1.0.0-alpha.1   1.0.0-alpha.1                                                                                                         
1.0.0-alpha.beta        1.0.0-alpha.beta                                                                                              
1.0.0-beta      1.0.0-beta                                                                                                            
1.0.0-beta.2    1.0.0-beta.2                                                                                                          
1.0.0-beta.11   1.0.0-beta.11                                                                                                         
1.0.0-rc.1      1.0.0-rc.1                                                                                                            
1.0.0   1.0.0
```

Assuming this works, this could simplify the `cmp_semver/1` function greatly.

```
def cmp_semver2($other): semver_key as $a | ($other|semver_key) as $b |
    if $a == $b then 0
    elif $a > $b then 1
    else -1 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all the objects where the version is "1.2.0", you can use string comparison :

```
jq --arg target 1.2.0 '
    map(select(.version == $target))' input.json
```

If you want the objects with version greater than 1.2.7, then:

```
jq --arg target 1.2.7 '
    def triple($i): $i | [splits("[.-]") | tonumber? // .];
    map(select(triple(.version) > triple($target)))' input.json
```

Comment: The point is: jq can compare arrays of numbers not only with `==` and ` !=` but also with `>`, ` <`, `>=` and ` <=`. This maps perfectly to the semantic of version numbers.

Comment: @Philippe - I'd add a caveat about the requirement that "pre-release < release", and also for efficiency, precompute triple($target) before invoking `map`.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I could do some ugly regex hack here

You could also use a simple regex hack if the semver strings do not need to be checked for correctness.  For example, consider the following:

```
# Ignore build metadata as it is irrelevant for comparisons:
# this means we can use == on the semver results to 
# determine equality of precedence.
# Note also that the following accords with the requirements
# about pre-release versions, notably:
# "Identifiers consisting of only digits are compared numerically."
# "Numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric identifiers."
def semver:
  sub("\\+.*";"") | [scan("[^-.]+") | tonumber? // .];
```

Since a valid semver string always begins with three components none of which can have superfluous leading zeros, and since jq's built-in ordering is so friendly (as per the comment by @A.H.), `semver` as defined above should make it quite easy to compare valid semver strings. However, since the spec requires that "pre-release" < "release", some care is required for non-trivial semantic version strings:

```
# Compare two semver arrays ensuring in particular that:
# pre-release < release
# identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII sort order;
# numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric identifiers.
def semver_less_than($array):
  if .[:3] == $array[:3] and length > 3 and ($array|length) == 3 then true
  else . < $array
  end;
```

The above is sufficient to pass the following sequence of tests included in the Semver 2.0 specification document:

```
1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.
```

However, since your example only has trivial semver specs, you could get away with:

```
# Filter for finding .version greater than 1.2.7 
("1.2.7" | semver) as $v
| map(select( (.version|semver) > $v))
```

---

Caveat: It's quite likely the above needs some improvement.  Tweaks or counterexamples would be welcome.

Comment: Here's a [jqplay.org demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5uUMGG9v6FW) using [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 suggested RegEx](https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string) adapted to `jq`.

Comment: ... [precedence](https://semver.org/#spec-item-11) isn't difficult, but it's not completely trivial.

Comment: @rickhg12hs - The documentation of semver_less_than/1 was mainly borrowed from the 2.0 spec requirements.  Is there a case the implementation doesn't cover?

Comment: It gets a bit more complicated when comparing the prerelease/build parts of the version which makes generalizing the version to an array not really possible except for the simplest of cases. Specifically when it comes to comparing the corresponding components in the dot separated string and comparing numeric values as numbers.

Comment: @JeffMercado. semver now discards the build string, and I've verified that the semver_less_than passes the quoted sequence of tests specified in the Semver 2.0 specification.  Have I missed something?